# Category relationship is giving error when I try to acces category through post

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

When I try to access articles vie category it works properly here is `category.php` model

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
}
```

but when I try to access category name view article it doesn't work as it's supposed to, I made I mistake there and trying to fix it, but no luck so far. here is the Article model

```
public function category(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\category');
}
```

and there is a table for relation those two to each others it's called `article_category` in page where I get all articles for the given tag, I want to do something like `$article->category->name` there is something sound very wrong to me but I can't figure it out.
The error I'm receiving is

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category.article_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `category` where `category`.`article_id` = 1 and `category`.`article_id` is not null limit 1) (View: C:\wamp64\www\loremipsum\bluhbluhbluh\articleByTag.blade.php)

Btw the way I save the relationship for the `article_category` when an article is created is

```
$article->category()->sync($request->category, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said that article might have only one category. In this case, delete pivot table and add `category_id` into the `articles` table.

Then in the `Article` model define this relationship:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

And in the `Category` model:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
}
```

When you'll do that, you'll be able to access article's category with:

```
$article->category->name
```

Comment: But don't you think that I won't be able to do many things such as counting relationships and giving recommended lists and stuff?

Comment: @Nikonah you'll be able to do all the same stuff.

Comment: this is the only reason why I ended up not saving category id inside article table. it feels harder to work with

Comment: @Nikonah it's not a reason to reinvent the wheel and use many-to-many instead of one-to-many. And it's actually easier to work with a one-to-many relationship. And it's faster too.

Comment: For some reason I'm not so confertable about this but it works pretty well

Answer (score 1):

You have the relationship established incorrectly. Remove the intermediate table and add `category_id` to the articles table.

Comment: Bu article might have only 1 category

Comment: Then you have a one to many and don't need the article_category intermediate table.

Comment: well I think that is correct, but even when I make it  `belongstomany` in `category `model it still doesnt let me access `$article->category->name`. When I write `$article->category`  than it gives me it's relationship too but when trying to get `name` it says **Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: That's because it's now  a many to many, you would have many categories. So you'd have to do something like `$article->categories->each->name`. But you really want the one to many as described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Relationships are not set correctly

`Category` model should be like :

```
 class Category extends Model 
 {

     protected $table='category';

    //give me all articles associated with the given category
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }
}
```

And `Article` model

```
class Article extends Model 
{
   protected $table='article';

   //get the category associated with the given article
   public function category()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
   }
}
```

for attaching articles to a category:

```
$article->category()->associate($category)->save();
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I really think the error might be caused by the table name I have. Their names are like: `artilce`, `category`, `article_category`

Comment: When I try this it gives an error both way. can't access category through article and can't access article through category

Comment: @Nikonah don't need `article_category` anymore because they don't have   many-to-many relationship

Comment: what is the name of articles table in DB ? article or articles ?

Comment: `article` and category is `category`

Comment: so add protected $table='article' and   protected $table='category' to relatives models as in updated answer

Comment: I actually used to do it that way but than added pivot table, Because I feel like I will be making recommendations and stuff depending on the relationship counts. or removing relationships which are not getting used. I think I will have so much trouble if I put `category_id` inside article table